# Бот не отправляет сообщение в канал

Tags: telegram, бот

Создал простого бота для телеграмма, который должен отправлять сообщение в канал. Скопировал айди канала, выдал алминку, в botfather дал возможность писать в каналы.

Бот после попытки отправить крашиться с причиной что его нету в канале, хотя я его добавил и выдал админку

Comment: прикрепите скрипт к вашему вопросу не понятно с чем работать?

Comment: покажите полный текст ошибки